# How do I share files between two versions of Ubuntu on different partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, files, partitioning

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 onto a new partition because I need to use a program that won't run on 14.04, which is the only OS on the machine right now.

Can I set things up so that files I save with that program in 12.04 are accessible to 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate (non-LVM) partition for that purpose. When you boot either of the Ubuntu versions you can mount that partition at the location where you want to have the data files.

For this to happen automatically you will have to add this partition to the `/etc/fstab` file in both your Ubuntu instances.

For testing, you can do first mount the partition manually and then later add it to `/etc/fstab`. Make sure to backup your `fstab` file first and have a live-disk at hand to restore it if there is a problem and your system won't boot. Also see [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

Another easier option is to run Ubuntu 12.04 in a VM and then mount a shared folder.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 at work, but some projects that I work on require Windows. I have Windows XP and Windows 7 running in VirtualBox VMs and have a folder on my Ubuntu machine that is mounted as a drive under Window. This is where I share and move data between Windows and Linux.

Comment: I've thought about using a virtual machine, but i'm concerned that the program i need to use is so resource intensive it would be a problem.  I suppose i should try it first.

Comment: A VM is also the safest option to just see how it works out. With respect to resources, if you were happy to run Ubuntu 12.04 on its own, then running it in a VM and giving it all resources it needs is virtually the same.  You only start up the machine when you need it and shut it down when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

A variant on NZD's approach is to share a `/home` partition; *however,* if you do this you should use different home directories. The easiest way to do this is to use different usernames, at least during installation. You can change your username after installation while keeping the original home directory. The end result is that the user `kim` (if that's what you use) has a home directory of `/home/kim` in Ubuntu 14.04, but `kim` in 12.04 has a home directory of, say, `/home/kim1204`.

Of course, if you've got an existing 14.04 installation that does *not* use a separate `/home` directory, adjusting that setup to have a separate `/home` directory will take a significant amount of effort, which may not be worth the bother.